# Is there a device that can be used to grate coconut and sweet potatoes electrically?

Tags: equipment, coconut

Does anyone know of a tabletop device that can grate coconut electrically? I love coconut products but most recipes call for grating the kernel which I do not like to do, it is a hard job, sometimes bits of my skin end end up in the grate. Long ago my brother made what he called a coconut mill by wrapping and fastening a nail punched tin plate around a cylindrical wooden block and then attaching a shaft through the block with a hand crank at one end he then attached the shaft through bearings fastened over a box for catching the finished product which was milled by pressing the coconut kernel between a narrow gap made by a rigid piece of material and the milling block and turning the hand crank.

I know many will say just use a blender but a good amount of people warn me not to blend coconuts for making the products of interest, they also warn me not to blend sweet potatoes for the famous sweet potato pudding the Caribbean people love so much, so the above device could be used for grating sweet potatoes for puddings as well,

I have searched a lot but can not find any electrical device that will give the same result as grating, is there something that can do this that I am not aware of?

If nothing exist I may have to use my brother's idea with an electrical motor and control to invent something.

Comment: How about cutting into slices and using the grater blade for a food processor?

Comment: Did you try a good cheese grater? Although fow sweet potatoes I'm affraid it'll not work.

Comment: It's not electrical, but what about a mandoline with a julienne blade?  It's pretty easy to get "grated" consistency from that, unless you're going for the really fine pulp-like consistency.  And most of the good ones have a top piece that you can use to hold the thing you're grating, so there's no danger to your hands.

Comment: **Google Search Warning** Several sites reccomend the **Anjali coconut scraper** I found all pages were the product or its images are infected by a Trojan.

Comment: @beli: I think your antivirus is overreacting, most of the sites I visited are fine.  Static images can't be infected either.

Comment: @Nick No problem. I collected ten insects from Indian pages in my quarentine box in two minutes.

Comment: @Nick : static images *can* be infected, such as [PNG](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2010-1205) , [TIFF](http://secunia.com/advisories/27213/) and [JPEG](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/ms04-028.mspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it can grate a hard cheese, it can grate a coconut.  I have a grating attachment on my kitchen aid that works great, but you can also use the grating disk on your food processor as justkt stated above.

Or if you REALLY use a lot of coconut and want the ultimate unitasker, you can buy an electric coconut grater. http://www.pioneercreativekitchenaccessories.co.uk/coconutgrater.htm

I just don't use that much coconut personally.

Comment: did you mean unitasker there?

Comment: We use coconuts here like the Italians use pasta, thanks for the link.

Comment: @Simmerdown, yes thank you!  At least someone is paying attention.  :)

Comment: I regularly use my food processor for grating, and the only issue is that at the end of each chunk of (whatever), it'll often get sucked in between the lid and grating disk, without actually getting grated.  For cheese and such, it helps to slow down when you've still got about 2 cm / 1 inch left, and use the next chunk to push, as it'll have more friction than against the plastic from the pusher for the feed tube.  You'll still end up with the problem on the last one, but it saves me time having to stop to clear it between each chunk being fed in.  (it's particularly messy w/ cheese)

Comment: Seems like the like doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 5):

Check this out:

[Presto 02910 SaladShooter Electric Slicer/Shredder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006IV0R)

[image: Product Image]

I haven't used it personally, but two of the top 3 reviews mention using it for grating both potatoes and coconuts.  There's also a "professional" version that's probably a bit more versatile/reliable.

Considering how silly the idea sounds, it seems to have gotten some pretty rave reviews and is also inexpensive.  So give it a try maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a KitchenAid stand mixer.  Then you can get the slicer/shredder attachment that will do all that you desire and more.

Yes, I know it's a large expense.  I'm even going to tell you to get the heavy duty one (I bought a 500 and eventually gave it to a friend and got the 600) because it will last you forever and you can use it for everything.

I make all of my bread in it.  I make cole slaw.  I make pasta and noodles.  And, yes, you can grate coconut.  If you have it you will use it nearly every day (assuming you cook that much).

To defray the costs some, you can pick up a refurb one from KitchenAid directly.  What they have varies, so you can check back for the model you want. http://www.shopkitchenaid.com/sub_category.asp?HDR=outlet&CAT=outletrefurb

Or REALLY defray the costs and get someone(s) to buy it for you.  But be specific.  You want at least the 5 quart, not Artisan, model...6 quart is better.

Comment: These seems more than a little bit overkill.  Yes, stand mixers are great versatile tools if you can spare the expense and the counter space; this guy just wants to grate coconuts.  It's like recommending a propane torch to light a few birthday candles.

Comment: A propane torch _would_ get around the problem of matches burning down while lighting lots of candles.